# Php: get response from a posted form on an external service

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

This would seem an easy task, but I can't get it to work.

I need to access some data publicly provided by the Bank of Mexico. The data is available through a form you can find at the link: http://www.banxico.org.mx/SieInternet/consultarDirectorioInternetAction.do?accion=consultarCuadro&idCuadro=CP5&locale=es
You can see an example of the data I need by clicking on the button "html" on the top left section. Once that table is opened I know how to fetch the data I need and work with them. However, I'd like to have this as an automated task so that the script can check regularly when new data is available.

So, I am trying to use file_get_contents() along with stream_context_create() to post the parameters I need and open the result page, so I can work with it.

I tried a few different ways (first I was using http_post_fields() ), but nothing seems to work.
Right now my code is this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.banxico.org.mx/SieInternet/consultarDirectorioInternetAction.do?accion=consultarSeries';
$data = array(
'anoFinal' => 2015,
'anoInicial' => 2015,
'formatoHTML.x' => 15,
'formatoHTML.y' => 7,
'formatoHorizontal' => false,
'idCuadro' => 'CP5',
'locale' => 'es',
'sector' => 8,
'series' => 'SP1',
'tipoInformacion' => '',
'version' => 2
);

$postdata = http_build_query($data);

$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postdata
  )
 );

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

//returns bool(false)
?>
```

What am I missing? I noticed that the page does in fact return nothing if wrong parameters are sent (as you can see by opening simply http://www.banxico.org.mx/SieInternet/consultarDirectorioInternetAction.do?accion=consultarSeries without any post data: nothing is returned), thus I'm not sure whether the post is successful but nothing is returned because some parameters are wrong, or if the code is wrong.

The posted data should be fine, as I copied them directly from a successfull query I made manually.
What am I missing?

Comment: You forgot to explain what the problem is. You just say "does not work".

Comment: Well, as it returns bool(false), that clearly is not the data I'm trying to fetch.

Comment: Add `'ignore_errors' => true` to your context, and see what you get then. Also, do a `var_dump($http_response_header);` afterwards, to see if the remote server answers with an error code.

Comment: Looking at the request details in browser console, you’ll see that a session id is send via cookie as well – so it might be that you need request the form page first, to get one. (Using cURL instead of file_get_contents will make this a lot easier.) And if they “protect” their form against requests without a valid session, it might also mean the don’t _want_ you to make automated requests for that data – so please go and check that with them first. (Read their ToS, and if its not in there, ask them.)

Comment: Hi, thanks, that was the advice I needed. I checked how to sent post data through cURL and it worked like a charm. If you make an answer of it I'll accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out cURL is a better way to do this, thanks to CBroe for the advice.

Here is the fixed code I am using, if someone else needs it:

```
<?php
//$url and $data are the same as above

//initialize cURL
$handle = curl_init($url);

//post values
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//set to return the response
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute
$response = (curl_exec( $handle ));
?>
```